# Get URL/anchor inside an onclick function binded to an anchor link AFTER following this link

Tags: javascript, html

## Context

CSS lack a "a:current" selector or access to the current URL, so I am trying to code vanilla JS to color the links in my menu which link to the same page/anchor.

I run a function each time I click on an anchor link to check for each menu link if it corresponds to the new anchor. Problem : document.URL refers to the URL BEFORE clicking the link. Please note that I think I can color my links in a different way, but this is not part of the question (you can comment if you have advices).

## Code to reproduce

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var check_anchor = function()
      {
        document.getElementById('url_log').innerHTML = document.URL;
      }
    </script>
    <a href='#anchor_1' onclick='check_anchor();'>Anchor 1</a>
    <a href='#anchor_2' onclick='check_anchor();'>Anchor 2</a>
    <a href='#anchor_3' onclick='check_anchor();'>Anchor 3</a>
    <p>URL is <span id='url_log'></span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Example :

When you click anchor 2 : "file:///home/[...]/Anchor_Example.html"

When you click anchor 3 : "file:///home/[...]/Anchor_Example.html#anchor_2"

When you click anchor 1 : "file:///home/[...]/Anchor_Example.html#anchor_3"

When you click anchor 1 : "file:///home/[...]/Anchor_Example.html#anchor_1"

(in that order : there is "a delay" : the URL printed is the URL before clicking the link. What I want is when you click anchor 1 : "file:///home/[...]/Anchor_Example.html#anchor_1")

## Question

Is it easily possible to get the URL after following an anchor link, or call the onClick event after following the link ?
If so, how would you do it ?

Sorry if this question seems dumb or have already been answered (I looked for it without success).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where `window.onhashchange` comes in handy.

[Check it out on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Not a dumb question at all.

Anytime inside that event handler you feel you want to know what the new URL is, you can use `location.href` or to get just the changed part (the hash) use `location.hash`

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
    console.log(location.hash);  // new hash/anchor location
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine, and easier than applying an onclick event to all anchor links. Thank you !

Just by curiosity, is there a way to call an onclick/on* function after doing the "normal event" (for example checking a checkbox. I didn't try but I think it works the same way : the event function is called, and after the chekbox is checked) ?

Comment: @Seipas yeah most events have a method you can call on the element.  For instance, inside the `onhashchange` event handler you could have `document.getElementById("my-element").focus()` or `.click()` or `.blur()` etc.  Doing what you're asking shouldn't be more than using `.click()` but if you end up wanting to take it further like entering text in an input field, you'll run into issues trying to detect that change somewhere else since simply setting `element.value = "new value"` won't trigger the `onChange` event.  Hope this helps :)

Comment: Well, thank you for this explanation but this isn't what I meant. Is there a way to do something like $<a href="#id" afterClicking="foo();" />$ or $onclick="this.followthelink(); foo();"$ ?
Your above solution work fine but I was just wondering, and I have the feeling that I might want to do this one day.

Comment: ah then you would just say `if ( location.hash === "#id" ) { return foo(); }`